# I try to copy from raw to external memory but it does not work

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-file

Good,

I am trying to `open a pdf` document `from my raw folder`, but I have read that it can not be opened directly from the raw folder, so I am copying it to external memory.

The problem is that I do `not copy the file to external memory` in order to open it.

This is my code:

```
public class OpenPdf {

private static final String TAG = "Open pdf";

public OpenPdf(Context ctx) {
if (checkMemory()){
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "There is access to the SD and you can write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    openPDF(ctx);
}else {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "No access to SD or can not write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

private boolean checkMemory(){
boolean sdAvailable = false;
boolean sdAccessWriter = false;
boolean value = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    sdAvailable = true;
    sdAccessWriter = true;
}else if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)){
    sdAvailable = true;
    sdAccessWriter = false;
}

if(sdAvailable && sdAccessWriter){
    value = true;
}
return value;
}

public void openPDF(Context ctx){

try {
    copyFile(ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.avisolegal), new FileOutputStream(new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "Documents/avisolegal.pdf")));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    File pdfFile = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "Documents/avisolegal.pdf");
    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    ctx.startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Fail to open file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i(TAG, "Fail to open file" + e);
}

}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
}
```

And these are the permissions on the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can I have the file copied to open it?

This is the error log:

```
03-15 12:53:26.976 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/radio.ecca.gesenecca/files/Documents/avisolegal.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at radio.ecca.gesenecca.Recursos.OpenPdf.openPDF(OpenPdf.java:59)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at radio.ecca.gesenecca.Recursos.OpenPdf.<init>(OpenPdf.java:30)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at radio.ecca.gesenecca.MainActivity$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:89)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
03-15 12:53:26.979 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
03-15 12:53:26.980 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca W/System.err:     ... 19 more
03-15 12:53:27.139 5267-5566/radio.ecca.gesenecca V/RenderScript: 0x9d2a3000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
03-15 12:53:44.030 5267-5267/radio.ecca.gesenecca I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@73b6028 time:138471792
```

Thank you very much in advance, I am learning a lot thanks to this community.

I'm sorry, I accidentally deleted the question.

**EDIT 1:**

If I change the route by "/avisolegal.pdf". It does not display the error, but does not copy the file to that path.

Comment: The directory /Documentos/ does not exist. So use mkdir() to create the dir first.

Comment: I tried to create the folder before copying the file, but it does not give an error and does not create the folder either. try {
            File dir = new File(ctx.getFilesDir() + "/Documents");
            dir.mkdir();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "Fail to make a folder" + e);
        }

Comment: You should only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist. Further you should check the return value of mkdir as it will return false if it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it is that does not create the directory not once. Once you verify that you create it, I will validate your existence so that it does not error.

Comment: That is nonsense. And it should be  File dir = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "Documents");

Comment: `state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();`. You do not have to look at that if you later will save to getFilesDir(). Moreover you do not need read or write permisdion if you read or write to getFilesDir().

Comment: You cannot see that folder as getFilesDir() is internal private memory for your app only. What did you do trying to see the folder?

Comment: I do not understand? I am trying to use external memory. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I have tested with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () but it does not create the folder

Comment: `new File(ctx.getFilesDir(),`. Now that is your code. You make a mess with your code using both internal and external paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved my problem, I leave it here so that they can see it and I can help them

The first thing I did, was to ask the user to write permissions to the external memory.

```
static final Integer WRITE_EXST = 0x3;

askForPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXST);


   private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {

            //This is called if user has denied the permission before
            //In this case I am just asking the permission again
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
        }
    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " ya han sido consedidos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        OpenPdf openPdf = new OpenPdf(getApplicationContext());
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permisos consedidos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        OpenPdf openPdf = new OpenPdf(getApplicationContext());
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permisos denegados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}
```

And this is my class that copies the raw file to the external memory and then opens it.

```
public class OpenPdf {

private static final String TAG = "Copiar fichero" ;

public OpenPdf(Context ctx) {

    if (checkMemory()){
        //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Hay acceso a la SD y se puede escribir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try
        {
            File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            openPDF(ctx,ruta_sd);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Ficheros", "Error al escribir el fichero en la tarjeta SD " + ex);
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "No hay acceso a la SD o no se puede escribir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private boolean checkMemory(){
    boolean sdAvailable = false;
    boolean sdAccessWriter = false;
    boolean value = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if(state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
        sdAvailable = true;
        sdAccessWriter = true;
    }else if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)){
        sdAvailable = true;
        sdAccessWriter = false;
    }

    if(sdAvailable && sdAccessWriter){
        value = true;
    }
    return value;
}

public void openPDF(Context ctx, File ruta){

    try {
        copyFile(ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.avisolegal), new FileOutputStream(new File(ruta, "avisolegal.pdf")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   try {
        File pdfFile = new File(ruta, "avisolegal.pdf");
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error al abrir el archivo.\nDebe tener un visor de archivos PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "Error al abrir el archivo" + e);
    }

}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

The problem was in the permissions for the new versions of android and the route I was using to copy the file.

A greeting and thank you very much for the help